# "Print only" page break in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, printing

I have a long report in SSRS with 3 tablix. I would like to have it in a single page when viewed in the browser, but when printed i want to have each tablix on it's own page. 
Is it possible to define page breaks that only applies to printing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make conditional page breaks but I think that this issue that you want to do is impossible.

Comment: I think you are right... I dropped the idea of "Print only page breaks"

Answer (score 0):

see if this might help, the idea behind was to insert a text box in my footer and to print this text box only on even pages:

=iif(Globals!PageNumber Mod 2,True,False)

Let me know if this works